# Eclipse Neon CDT run configuration not setting environment variables

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt, eclipse-neon

I've just upgraded from Eclipse Kepler to Neon.3 and discovered that setting environment variables in the run configuration does not work unless you run under the debugger.  As of 2017-02-06, this was identified as a regression issue in Neon.3 but I've been unable to find a fix.

Has anyone else seen this issue and found either a fix or a workaround?

Comment: I did find a work around: define the LD_LIBRARY_PATH as an environment variable before starting Eclipse.  It has it's limitations: if you need a different setting for different run configurations, this won't work.  Every time you change workspaces, you may have to exit, define LD_LIBRARY_PATH, and restart Eclipse with the correct workspace.  A pain, but it works.

Comment: I have just submitted my fix for this https://bugs.eclipse.org/508948 If you are able to test CDT 9.3 RC2 which will be released in the coming days that would be great.

Comment: Thanks Jonah!  Might take me a few days but I'll see if I can get to it next week.